# CKEditor in multiple Angular web components that run in a frame

Tags: angular, ckeditor, web-component

I'm new and a junior developer, so I'm not too advanced in Angular development.
I've been trying to find a solution for a problem we have at work for days now, but wasn't able to find a working solution.

The problem:
We have two Angular web components that both use the CKEditor (5). Both web components run in a frame that allows us to switch between them. We have no access to the frame and cannot configure anything there.
(Sadly, due to the work contract I can't get too much more into detail about the frame, but if you have questions regarding that I'll try to answer as much as possible) - Essentially, upon switching between both applications, the page won't reload.
The 2nd of our two applications has just been made into a web component, which is when we noticed our error - Without a page reload we can't switch between applications anymore due to the CKEditor, it throws a "`ckeditor-duplicated-modules`" error in the console.

`Uncaught CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules`

Upon investigating we noticed that for the window the properties `window.CKEDITOR_VERSION` and `window.CKEDITOR_TRANSLATIONS` are still set after leaving one web component and try to switch to another. Like I said, we have to reload the entire page to get it to work again.

We've tried two things so far:
First thing was to set both properties to `null` in the app.component.ts as the first thing in ngOnInit.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  if((window as any).CKEDITOR_VERSION) {
    (window as any).CKEDITOR_VERSION = null;
    (window as any).CKEDITOR_TRANSLATIONS = null;
  }
}
```

At first glance it seemed to work and we were able to switch between both applications again, but then we noticed that we couldn't use the CKEditor at all anymore. (Sort of expected behavior, I assume)

Then we tried to use conditional module imports in the app.module.ts like this:

```js
imports: [
  (window as any).CKEDITOR_VERSION ? CKEditorModule : []
]
```

That also didn't work and the application wouldn't even build anymore.

I'm out of ideas on how to fix the problem, because after 3 days of researching possible solutions it doesn't seem that anyone has ever encountered this problem before. So I really hope someone is able to help me out here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

it may behoove you to turn these into standalone components and load the modules required for cdkeditor into both of the standalone components - this way they are initialized as two separate element.

https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components

I would've just made a comment but apparently my reputation is not high enough to do so.

Comment: Will look into that, not sure if we are able to do so, though. Due to the environment we're kind of limited.